# google plus page insight data using google API - c#

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-apis-explorer

google plus page insight data using google API, i was unable to find api explorer for google plus page insight's data.
i have registered the page details here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup, waiting for its approval.

is there a api-explorer for it, provided by google? because i didn't found anything here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/ for google plus page analytics data, where i can get the dimension and metrics details etc, etc.

please someone suggest me something
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ Pages API is not available for anyone who hasn't applied and been accepted as an API partner.

The [Google+ Platform Insights dashboard](https://developers.google.com/+/features/analytics) is already available and should provides the available analytics. What are you looking to do with data access?

Comment: Hi @class, thanx for your reply :)
i have seen the dashboard on GPlus, i want the data of +1s, Demographic and Geographic into my application from GPlus page using its APi, as i have mentioned i have filled this form :  https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup

Comment: Got it, thanks for the feature suggestions. Please star or add your recommendations to the Google+ feature issue tracker to help the Google+ platform team prioritize this. https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list